# Detecting Several Knee Points with Python

Tags: python, detection, point, curve

While using the Knee [library](https://github.com/arvkevi/kneed) in Python I found that for a certain curve shape the Knee is detected correctly, as shown below (orange cross):

[image]

On the other hand, for this shape, the Knee is detected as the maximum point:

[image]

Is there any way to correct this?

Thanks!

Comment: really hard to answer this question without knowing what you did

Comment: Just looked the library for the first time and there's a streamlit app you can run to interactively tune the parameters. did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at both the library and the paper it is based on, it appears to only work for [convex/concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) functions. From [the paper](https://raghavan.usc.edu//papers/kneedle-simplex11.pdf):

> Note that we assume that the curves under consideration have negative
> concavity. For curves with consistently positive
> concavity (e.g., forming “elbows” rather than knees) it is trivial
> to invert the graph by ...

So if you want to handle functions like the one you've shown here, you'll need a different algorithm.